# How to copy whole columns from one sheet to the next if it finds a match in the header in sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba, helper

I'm working with two sheets. One sheet has the full raw data while the other has a select few headers from sheet 1. If it finds a match on the header, i need it to copy the full column from sheet one to sheet 2

[image: Sheet 1]

and it copies it to sheet 2

[image: Sheet 2]

Here is my code so far but i can't figure out how to break the loop so that it goes through every column on sheet 1 until it finds a match:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ShtOne As Worksheet, ShtTwo As Worksheet
Dim shtOneHead As Range, shtTwoHead As Range`enter code here`
Dim headerOne As Range, headerTwo As Range

Set ShtOne = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ShtTwo = Sheets("Sheet2")
'row count
Dim b As Long
b = ShtOne.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'column count in sheet 1
Dim a As Long
a = ShtOne.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'column count in sheet 2
Dim c As Long
c = ShtTwo.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim lastCol As Long
'get all of the headers in the first sheet, assuming in row 1
lastCol = ShtOne.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set shtOneHead = ShtOne.Range("A1", ShtOne.Cells(1, lastCol))

'get all of the headers in second sheet, assuming in row 1
lastCol = ShtTwo.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set shtTwoHead = ShtTwo.Range("A1", ShtTwo.Cells(1, lastCol))

'stops the visual flickering of files opening and closing - run at the background
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'start loop from first row to last row
'For i = 1 To a
i = 1
j = 0
'actually loop through and find values
For Each headerOne In shtOneHead
j = j + 1
    For Each headerTwo In shtTwoHead
    'copy and paste each value
            If headerTwo.Value = headerOne.Value Then

    'copies one row at a time (a bit slow)
               ' headerOne.Offset(i, 0).Copy
               ' headerTwo.Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    'copies whole rows at a time
            ShtOne.Columns(i).Copy ShtTwo.Columns(j)
            i = i + 1
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit For
        End If
    Next headerTwo
Next headerOne

'Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I would adjust approach to **only** loop through headers on second sheet and then use a `Range.Find` on row with headers on first sheet. From there you can build your copy & paste range from the found column.

Comment: Iterate just the headers on Sheet 1 and use [`Range.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to find the correct column on sheet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your headers are on row 1 for both sheets and that you will always be pasting on the second row on `Sheet2`.

---

Only loop through your column headers on the second sheet. Use `Range.Find` to search for each header on `Sheet1`. If the header is found, copy and paste accordingly

```
Sub Headerz()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim LC As Long, i As Long, LR As Long
Dim Found As Range

LC = ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For i = 1 To LC
    Set Found = ws1.Rows(1).Find(ws2.Cells(1, i).Value)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then

        LR = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, Found.Column), ws1.Cells(LR, Found.Column)).Copy
        ws2.Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If

    Set Found = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: hey urdearboy. i have a question. why is my script rerunning the loop and copying and pasting values after it goes through the first selection. more specifically, i have 8 columns in my second sheet that will match my first sheet. I have multiple blanks and then i have information in the next 20 blanks that won't match my first sheet. but it is going through all of those loops and then replacing those with the first 8 columns repetitively.